# td link are not working properly in a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am working on  datatable and trying to linking table data of each data:

```html
<td style="overflow: hidden;" data-link="<%= receivemail_show_path("id" => trash_mail.id) %>">
    <%= trash_mail.date.strftime("%e %b")%>
</td>
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $("td[data-link]").click(function() {    
        window.location = $(this).data('link');  
        // window.document.location = $(this).data("href");  
    });
});
```

My problem is that this link works only for the first page on the datatable Can anyone kindly tell me why it should behave like this?

Comment: Use event delegation since the other `td`s are generated dynamically .... `$("table").on('click', "td[data-link]", function() {.....`

Comment: Thanks ...it work well................